# World regions as tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

(I am new here.) I have observed the following. Looks like the majority of active population of this SE is American. When I ask a question, I get answers, for which I need quite a bit of further reading to interpret them. E.g. [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/89840/21382) the comments and the answers started pretty quickly to explain why the situation in question is not typical for the US electrical standards. But since I am in Europe, it doesn't answer my question.

Other examples include:

- differences in how things are measured, beyond the simple millimetre-inch scaling (American gauges for wire thickness vs. European cross-section area in square millimetres quickly make me lose the point)
- different wire colour codes
- traditionally different methods or materials (e.g. for wire connection [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10144/21382) and for wall materials [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/80873/21382))
- etc.

In many cases, it is easy to ignore these differences, the question/answer readability is not impacted. But sometimes the whole point can be missed, or the text may get difficult to read if the regional differences are ignored/unknown.

Therefore I wonder if it makes sense to introduce the "regional tags", to help reading/answering questions.

Some more relevant links from Wikipedia:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring_in_North_America#Comparison_of_US_practices_with_other_countries
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist-on_wire_connector

Comment: These fall into the category of [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: @BMitch, very good, I didn't find it having searched for regions rather than locations.

Comment: I was lucky to have it appear in the "related" section on the right, otherwise I would have forgotten all about it. There's more details on tagging and the meta tag policy in the [help center](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), which includes a link to the above blog post.

Comment: @BMitch, but I disagree that these are meta-tags. Please see my arguments in the [answer](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/1180/21382) to the linked question. So though I agree it's a duplicate, I'd like to have it answered please.