# Should the UK tag be removed

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems as though it was [decided to not have regional tags](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/650/33), however, it appears that the [uk](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) tag actually does exist. Should this tag be removed?

Answer (score 4):

I believe it should be removed like other regional tags. If there's any value in tracking these as a sub category of another tag, I wouldn't be opposed to creating something like [electrical-uk](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-uk), but a situation like that should have a reason for the unique tag like local codes that do not apply to other countries. This would differ from plaster work in the UK, which is unlikely to be different from plaster work in other EU countries or even on the other side of the world.